# Show a particular dropdown after original dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have been trying to show 1 out of the 3 dropdowns on selection of a particular option in previous dropdown but I have only been able to hide the dropdown on clicking and not been able to show the next one.

```
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="class" id="label-class">
    Select your class
  </label>
  
  <!-- Dropdown options -->
  <select name="class" id="class"  onchange="select_class(this)">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Class...</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The above mentioned is my original dropdown and selection of an option in this should lead to display of corresponding dropdown.

```
<div class="TeachGroup" id="AClass">
  <label for="FieldA"> Here are your teachers </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="FieldA">
  <option>A TeaCher 1</option>
  <option>A TeaCher 2</option>
  <option>A TeaCher 3</option>
  <option>A TeaCher 4</option>
  <option>A TeaCher 5</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="TeachGroup" id="BClass">
  <label for="FieldB"> Here are your teachers </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="FieldB">
  <option>B TeaCher 1</option>
  <option>B TeaCher 2</option>
  <option>B TeaCher 3</option>
  <option>B TeaCher 4</option>
  <option>B TeaCher 5</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="TeachGroup" id="CClass">
  <label for="FieldC"> Here are your teachers </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="FieldC">
  <option>C TeaCher 1</option>
  <option>C TeaCher 2</option>
  <option>C TeaCher 3</option>
  <option>C TeaCher 4</option>
  <option>C TeaCher 5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

These are the three dropdowns amongst which one needs to be selected based on above dropdown selection like A leads to FieldA, B leads to displaying of FieldB and C leads to displaying of FieldC

```
    <script>
function select_class(a) {
    var x = (a.value || a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);  
//crossbrowser solution =)
   // alert('Type selected: ' +x); 
    //$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#class").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "C") {
    $('#CClass').show();
    $('#BClass').hide();
    $('#AClass').hide();
    
} if($(this).val() == "B") {
    $('#BClass').show();
    $('#AClass').hide();
    $('#CClass').hide();
    
   }
  if($(this).val() == "A"){
    $('#AClass').show();
    $('#BClass').hide();
    $('#CClass').hide();
    
  }
    //   $('#class').on('change', function(){
    //   var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
    //     $("div.form-group").hide();
    //     $("#show"+demovalue).show();
    // });
   });
    $("#class").trigger("change");
   // }
</script>

This is the script I have been running.
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); provide a proper [mre] of the issue directly inside the question instead.

Comment: I tried adding the code, it has been giving me an indentation error/formatting error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Added the code, here you go

Comment: You added a change handler via HTML attribute, and then inside the handler function, you are trying to add another change handler, this time using jQuery event handling - what is the point of that supposed to be?

Comment: I am new to javascript and have been referring to resources online to handle the change and then display that particular dropdown after selection of a particular tag in the original dropdown

Comment: _"to handle the change and then display that particular dropdown after selection"_ - but this is _one_ step, you handle the change event, and displaying the corresponding select field is _part of_ that "handling the change event". Adding another change handler _inside_ an already added change handler, that makes very little sense.

Comment: okay, i understand. What is recommended now code wise?

Comment: To add _one_ change handler function, and to do the necessary showing/hiding of elements in there.